# Change the position of Videoview by using onDragListener

Tags: android, android-view, android-videoview

I am using `VideoView` to play videos. I want to change its position when I Drag it from its original location to new location. I used following code:

```
video_view.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    float x=event.getX();
                    float y=event.getY();

                    int top=(int)x+height;
                    int bottom=(int)y+height;
                    int left=(int)x+width;
                    int right=(int)y+width;

                    video_view.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
                    v.invalidate();
```

and xml is

```
<VideoView 
android:id="@+id/video"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_width="100dp"/>
```

In above code, video_view is my object for `videoview`. But when I try to Drag it, nothing changes so am I doing anything wrong?? Or do I need to use `FrameLayout` because I am using relative layout here??

And also along with it I need little clarification on Difference between `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED` and `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED`

and

`DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED` and `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED`.. Thank you!!

Comment: You can found information about drag event here [Drag and Drop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html#AboutDragEvent)

Answer (score 2):

You have to start the drag process executing the startDrag method in your view:

```
video_view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you change your code to code below,this code work for me. :D

```
video_view.getRootView().setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {..your code..}
```